# fabricjs not all abject area is selectable

Tags: fabricjs

I use fabricjs library.
I added an image to the canvas -
but for some users not all image area is selectable.
When I write this code in seperate file it works perfect,
but when I insert the code to the website -
for some users not all the image area is selectable,
all the right side do not work:
The image doesn't move when the user click on the image's right side and drag the image - the image doesn't move,etc.

What can be the reason?

This is my code:

```
<svg width="600px" height="350px"><rect width="600" height="350" class="bg"/>
<foreignObject x="10" y="10" width="330" height="330">
    <body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 330px; height: 330px; border: 1px solid lightgray;">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:2px solid #000000"></canvas>
    </body>
</foreignObject>
<text x="10" y="20" fill="white">SVG with embedded Canvas</text> 
    <text x="0" y="0" fill="white">Data extent</text>
     </svg>
<script>
   fabric.Object.prototype.selectionColor ='rgba(255,119,0,0.3)';
   fabric.Object.prototype.cornerSize = 20;
   fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;
   fabric.Object.prototype.cornerColor = '#eee';
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 30, fill: '#f55', top: 100, left: 100 }));
     fabric.Image.fromURL(

'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png', 
    function(myImg) {
     
    //i create an extra var for to change some image properties
     var img1 = myImg.set({ left: 0, top: 0 ,width:150,height:150});
     img1.resizeFilter = new fabric.Image.filters.Resize({
         resizeType: 'hermite'
    });
     canvas.add(img1); 
    });
 </script>
```

This is the problametic page:
https://concepta.co.il/product/%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8-%D7%A2%D7%9D-%D7%98%D7%A7%D7%A1%D7%98-%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%92%D7%9C/

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

An incorrect selection area on an object is usually caused by not running `setCoords()` on the object after making a change to it programmatically.

https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/wiki/When-to-call-setCoords

Comment: Thank you for the answer! As I didn't get answer - I changed my code and didn't use SVG, So I can't check this solution/